# How do I add a Custom Attribute to a Grouped Product

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute

I have bought a template Smartwave Porto which has a feature called Featured Products. In order to display a featured product a custom attribute is used called sw_feature which is used to toggle whether said product is a featured product. It appears that this attribute is only available on simple products.

How do I make it so that I can use this attribute (or any other custom attribute) on other product types. It seems that Group Products are restricted to certain attributes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can used the code to create product attribute like this.

```
namespace Vendor\Extension\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'yourcode',
            [
                'group' => 'General',
                'label' => 'Feature Product',
                'type'  => 'int',
                'input' => 'boolean',
                'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
                'source' => '',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 1,
                'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'apply_to'                => 'simple,grouped'  
                'visible_on_front' => false
            ]
        );
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

NOTE: This code create product attribute for Simple and Group product.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful. I was able to find the code where I need to make the change.